# GEE Download data around buffers on multiplie points, adding coordinates of each point to table

Tags: google-earth-engine, buffer, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, centroids, feature-collection

I want to download a time series of the average pixel value of a buffer around a number of points. In the resulting table, I'd like to have the coordinates of each point as a variable. How to do this?

A strategy seems to be generating the centroids of the buffers and add as a feature, but I can't make the centroid value appear in the table.

Also, what is the .geo() variable in the resulting table in the example below?

[Code here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fra2683%2Fdefault%3AexampleMultipoints)

```
// set of points

var pointList= ee.List(
        [[-133.49345223488783, 28.4392489430013],
         [-134.28446785988783, 27.273691218174367],
         [-135.73466317238783, 27.351783369494303]]);


// turn them into a feature collection
var pointCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(pointList.map(function(p){
  var point = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {});
  return point;
}));

print(pointCollection);
Map.addLayer(pointCollection);

// generate the buffers
var bufferBy = function(size) {
  return function(feature) {
    return feature.buffer(size);   
  };
};

// adds the centroid to the buffer as a feature
var getCentroids = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({polyCent: feature.centroid()});
};

var pointCollectionBfs = ee.FeatureCollection(pointCollection.map(bufferBy(10000)).map(getCentroids));

print('points Bf',pointCollectionBfs);
Map.addLayer(pointCollectionBfs, {color: 'd63000'}, 'points');

////////////////        //////////////////
// IMAGE COLLECTION - MODIS-Aqua
////////////////        //////////////////
var start = ee.Date('2014-01-01');
var finish = ee.Date('2014-05-31');

var chla = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
  .filterDate(start,finish)
  .select('chlor_a');

var coll=pointCollectionBfs ;
var collName='pointBfs' ;

// CHLA
// chla mean
var chla_mean = chla.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: coll, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 3000
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('date', image.date());
    })
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('id', image.id());
      });
})
.flatten();

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: chla_mean,
  description: 'example_chla_mean_'+collName,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code prints in your csv table the coordinates of centroids as centroid_x, centroid_y (one column for each coordinate). I hope this helps.

```
// set of points

var pointList= ee.List(
        [[-133.49345223488783, 28.4392489430013],
         [-134.28446785988783, 27.273691218174367],
         [-135.73466317238783, 27.351783369494303]]);


// turn them into a feature collection
var pointCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(pointList.map(function(p){
  var point = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {});
  return point;
}));

print(pointCollection);
Map.addLayer(pointCollection);

// generate the buffers
var bufferBy = function(size) {
  return function(feature) {
    return feature.buffer(size);   
  };
};

// adds the centroid to the buffer as a feature
var getCentroids = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({polyCent: feature.centroid()});
};

var pointCollectionBfs = ee.FeatureCollection(pointCollection.map(bufferBy(10000))
  .map(getCentroids));

print('points Bf',pointCollectionBfs);
Map.addLayer(pointCollectionBfs, {color: 'd63000'}, 'buffers');

////////////////        //////////////////
// IMAGE COLLECTION - MODIS-Aqua
////////////////        //////////////////
var start = ee.Date('2014-01-01');
var finish = ee.Date('2014-05-31');

var chla = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
  .filterDate(start,finish)
  .select('chlor_a');

var coll = pointCollectionBfs ;
var collName='pointBfs' ;

// CHLA
// chla mean
var chla_mean = chla.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: coll, 
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    scale: 3000
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('mean', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('centroid_y', f.geometry().centroid().coordinates().get(1));
    })
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('centroid_x', f.geometry().centroid().coordinates().get(0));
    })
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('date', image.date());
    })
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('id', image.id());
      });
}).flatten();

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: chla_mean,
  description: 'example_chla_mean_' + collName,
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```